# Python download videos from HTTP URL with bad internet

Tags: python, download

I have problem with downloading videos from my server e.g. http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Cornaro%20USLUGE.mp4

All works perfectly when internet is OK, but when I disconnect LAN cable from Raspberry Pi and stay like that less than 10-15 seconds. But when internet is off more than 10-15 seconds, my download does not continue or videos are not properly downloaded (I merge them later with MP4Box and they need to be). If someone has suggestion how to solve this problem and help me I would appreciate it very much.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
import time
import commands
import requests
import shutil
from urllib2 import URLError

urls = ['http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/00 APPS OVERVIEW.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Cornaro USLUGE.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/ILIRIJA BIOGRAD 2016.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Restoran marina.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/HT Screens.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Hotels Touch - Tasks.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Croatia Full of life.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/04 PROJECTS.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/05 ATTEND.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Cornaro Hotel.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Plurato dron snimka 2.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Plurato dron snimka 2.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Plurato dron snimka 2.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Cornaro USLUGE.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Cornaro USLUGE.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Hotels Touch - Screens.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Hotels Touch - Screens.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Hotels Touch - Tasks.mp4',
'http://screensfiles.dbtouch.com/screens2/Companies/89/HD/Hotels Touch - Screens.mp4']

directory = "/home/pi/pythonSignage/current_playlist/videos_to_merge/"


i=1

for url in urls:

    i += 1
    print("current iter: ")
    print(i)

    if (len(urls) > 1):
        url_formatted = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "").replace("%20", "") + " "
    else:
        url_formatted = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "").replace("%20", "")

    url_formatted_name = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "").replace("%20", "").rstrip()

    while True:

        print("inside while true")
        try:
            """ method 0 doesn't work """
            print("try")
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=5)
            content = response.read()
            print("content")
            f = open(directory + url_formatted_name, 'wb')
            f.write(content)
            f.close()

            """ method 1 doesn't work """
            #video_fancy_downloader = urllib.FancyURLopener()
            #video_fancy_downloader.retrieve(url, directory + url_formatted_name)

            """ method 2 - doesn't work """
            #my_file = urllib.URLopener()
            #my_file = retrieve(url, directory + url_formatted_name)

            """ method 3 - doesn't work """
            #response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            #response.raise_for_status()
            #with open(directory + url_formatted_name, 'wb') as handle:
            #    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            #        handle.write(block)

        except:
            print("error download, sleep 5 sec")
            time.sleep(5)


print("end")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my problem. Maybe this is not best approach but it works.

Here is function for downloading video and returns response:

```
def do_download(destination, url):
    comm = ["wget", "-c", "-O", destination, "-t", "15000", "-T", "5", url]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(comm, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    tmp = proc.stdout.read()
    if "wget: unable to resolve host address" in tmp:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

core part of downloading function is almost the same, but now it calls `do_download` inside while loop and checks for response:

```
if os.path.isfile(directory+url_formatted_name) is False:
    print("must download file!")

    while downl_success is False:
        print("inside while true")
        try:
            print("try")

            while(do_download(directory + url_formatted_name, url) is False):
                print(" ------- inside while for download ----------- ")
                time.sleep(5)

            downl_success = True

            print("file downloaded fully!")
            break

        except HTTPError, e:
            print "HTTPError", e.code, url
            time.sleep(5)

        except URLError, e:
            print "URL Error", e.reason, url
            time.sleep(5)

else:
    print("file already downloaded no need to download it again!")
```